# Speed up regex matching in Python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose, you have hundreds of thousands of lines and hundreds of regexps.

How can you make this code faster?

I need the indexes of the two arrays, as output (in a file finally).

```
import re
from timeit import default_timer as timer

a = ['apple_789456',
     'banana_741',
     'pear_11112222',
     'orange_454545',
     'pineapple_7777888',
     'banana_999999'
    ]
regs = [r'ple.*?7',
        r'a.*?74',
        r'range.*?5',
        r'45'
       ]
regs_re = [re.compile(r) for r in regs]

start = timer()
for i in range(len(a)):
   for j in range(len(regs)):
      if re.search(regs_re[j],a[i]):
         print('regs_re['+str(j)+'] found in a['+str(i)+']: '+a[i])
print(timer() - start)
```

Comment: Just a thought. If speed is a requirement you should possibly look at another programming language for this task.

Comment: Did you profile the code to determine where the most time is spent? Otherwise any attempt may be wasted effort.

Comment: Some obvious improvements are not looking up `regs_re[i]` and `a[j]`, and not using `print` and string concatenation, in every iteration.

Comment: Also you might want to use the compiled re's `search` methods instead of the module-level function (not sure if it makes a difference).

Comment: Also you could try to apply one regex to larger chunks of text at once to weed out the negatives.

Comment: Further to @mkrieger1's comment, you might write something like the following (pseudo-code) `if str.include?('ple_') and str.match?(/ple.*?7/)...`.

Comment: Also, depending on what you know about the input strings, the regexes might be mutually exclusive. So if you have one match you know you can skip the others.

Comment: @mkrieger1, ...and if that's the case, it might be possible to order the regexes in terms of estimated likelihood of matching a string. Another possible avenue to investigate is whether the strings could be sorted in such a way that if a string matches a regex, test the next string against the same regex before going on to the others.

Comment: Your sample regexes are all just string matches. You'd go faster using `string.index()` rather than regular expressions. For the two-part items, that's `part1 = string.index("ple"); if (part1 && string.index("7", part1 + length(part1))): …` (my syntax may be slightly off, I'm not a python veteran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accelerate it would be to execute each expression only once on the whole text (concatenated lines).  This will not produce the results in the same order but will make it a few times faster on thousands of lines.

Obviously, printing as you go will completely screw up any time measurement so I placed results in a list to compare execution times.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from itertools import accumulate
start     = timer()
text      = "\n".join(a)                      # single string with all lines      
lineIndex = [i for i,c in enumerate(text) if c=="\n"] # map positions to line number
result    = []                                # accumulate results in a list
for j,expr in enumerate(regs):                # execute each expression only once
    previ = -1                                # finditer may find multiple occurrences on same line
    for m in re.finditer(expr,text):          # go through all occurrences
         i = bisect_left(lineIndex,m.start()) # determine line number
         if i == previ: continue
         previ = i         
         result.append((i,j))                 # build result list
print(timer() - start)
for i,j in result:
    print(f"regs_re[{j}] found i a[{i}]: {a[i]}")
```